# How does ApiControllerAttribute works as there is no implementation of it at all

Tags: asp.net-core, attributes

The `[ApiControllerAttribute]` does 4 things, for instance automatic model validtation. But when I look for its source code to override its behaviour there is no code inside: https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/blob/457ade0b771697ff6f99f8138098e223e56326d6/src/Mvc/Mvc.Core/src/ApiControllerAttribute.cs also the classes from which it inherits and the interfaces that it implements have no methods.
How does it do anything at all then?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Attributes in .NET are generally just annotations and act like markers that don’t run code on their own. There are just some attributes (e.g. `ValidationAttribute`) that also contain actual logic but those will then be triggered by other components.

In the case of the `[ApiController]` attribute, this just marks the class to have an annotation of type `IApiBehaviorMetadata`. There are then some places that check for the existence of such an attribute and then change the behavior.

In particular, there is the [`ApiBehaviorApplicationModelProvider`](https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/blob/2670c128d522473e146ff9f8159bfffdfe694cd9/src/Mvc/Mvc.Core/src/ApplicationModels/ApiBehaviorApplicationModelProvider.cs) which contains [the following check](https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/blob/2670c128d522473e146ff9f8159bfffdfe694cd9/src/Mvc/Mvc.Core/src/ApplicationModels/ApiBehaviorApplicationModelProvider.cs#L116-L126):

```cs
private static bool IsApiController(ControllerModel controller)
{
    if (controller.Attributes.OfType<IApiBehaviorMetadata>().Any())
    {
        return true;
    }

    var controllerAssembly = controller.ControllerType.Assembly;
    var assemblyAttributes = controllerAssembly.GetCustomAttributes();
    return assemblyAttributes.OfType<IApiBehaviorMetadata>().Any();
}
```

When the model provider finds an API controller, it will then apply some conventions, for example the [`InvalidModelStateFilterConvention`](https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/blob/2670c128d522473e146ff9f8159bfffdfe694cd9/src/Mvc/Mvc.Core/src/ApplicationModels/InvalidModelStateFilterConvention.cs) which basically just adds the MVC filter [`ModelStateInvalidFilter`](https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/blob/2670c128d522473e146ff9f8159bfffdfe694cd9/src/Mvc/Mvc.Core/src/Infrastructure/ModelStateInvalidFilter.cs) into the pipeline.

That way, actions within an API controller will then have an adjusted behavior, according to the selected conventions.

There are also other places, for example within the analyzers, that check for the existence of the API controller attribute, for example using an internal [`IsApiControllerAction` method](https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/blob/2670c128d522473e146ff9f8159bfffdfe694cd9/src/Mvc/Mvc.Api.Analyzers/src/ApiControllerFacts.cs#L28-L32).

Comment: Good answer. I did not know that.